# ScrollTop - working Firefox, not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html

Hi guys I have a script that when a div is clicked, it scrolls down to another section.
Then, when the button is clicked, it scrolls back to the top.

It's working in Firefox - but not in Chrome. I have tried every version of code on StackOverflow and I can't get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var offset = 20; //Offset of 20px
        $("#offer_table").toggle();

        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#section5").offset().top + offset
    }, 2000);

    });
    });     

</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to put this `$("#section5").offset().top + offset` into a variable and use that variable inside the animation definition, like:

```
...
var x1 = $("#section5").offset().top + offset;
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: x1
    }, 2000);
...
```

Comment: Johannes thanks for the suggestion -- still could not get it to work in Chrome!

Answer (score 0):

Your script as posted works (tested in Chrome), but it does not do what you want it to. In your script, when you click on the button, the page scrolls to #section5, and the #offer_table button toggles show/hide. What exactly do you want it to do? You mention the sections - do you want the page to scroll down to the next section when you click on the current one?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var offset = 20; //Offset of 20px
        $("#offer_table").toggle();

        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#section5").offset().top + offset
    }, 2000);

    });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="offer_table">Offer</button>
<button id="button">Button</button> 
<div id="section1">section 1</div>
<div id="section2">section 2</div>
<div id="section3">section 3</div>
<div id="section4">section 4</div>
<div id="section5">section 5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, I got rid of Toggle to make it easier, still can't get it to work in Chrome, I'm going to try this https://codepen.io/pawelgrzybek/pen/akqXro.